# How to send data from laravel to a redis queue implemented using Bull queue

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, nestjs, bull-queue

I have implemented Bull queue in nestjs project but want producer to be a laravel project.
I use following command to produce

`Redis::command('zadd', ['bull:test:delayed', 1, $data]);`

and at consumer use

```
@Processor('test')
export class ConsumerProcessor {
  @Process({concurrency:13})
  handle(j: Job<unknown>) {
    this.logger.log(j.id);
  }
}
```

The $data added at producer is accessible via job.id, how can I access it using job.data and have a unique id? What changes needs to be done at producer side?

Comment: Did you succeed at this? I am trying to implement a similar solution

Comment: Did anyone of you guys found an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code works:

```
A="some unique identifier";
Redis::command("hmset",['bull:<queuename>:<A>', "data" , json_encode($data)]); 
Redis::command('zadd', ['bull:<queuename>:delayed', 1, A]);
```

Comment: Do I first need to fetch the latest ID (for using it as identifier)? Is delayed really the correct one where the ID should be added? Or shouldnt it be the wait-queue?

Comment: In my case I was using a UUId for identifier so fetching was not required. Also, I had to delay the queueing, so I added it in delayed. This hack works for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I used https://github.com/HackThisSite/PHP-Bull-Scheduler to add jobs (works only with Predis)

---

Also tried https://github.com/ilzrv/php-bull-queue today to get phpredis support (requires php7.4+)

Comment: Seems like this package was created 2 months later in Nov '20.